# What is the correct site to ask questions about typing Kurdish diacritics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is the current site to ask a question about Kurdish diacritics? Specifically how to type Kurdish diacritics using Chromebook?

Answer (score 9):

It's more of a question about how to input certain characters on your Chromebook, rather than a question about Kurdish diacritics alone, so therefore [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook) is the way to go.

Comment: What I'm asking is if there is a way to insert the hārākāt (arabic vowels) using the keyboard. For example using the Farsi keyboard if I type the capital U it inputs the 'fatah'. I was just curious if the Kurdish keyboard in general could do the same thing or not.

Comment: @jastako that definitely sounds like a Super User question then. Take a look at the tag [input-languages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/input-languages). If you were asking about what a fatah sounds like in Kurdish when combined with certain consonants, then that would be a language usage question that would be off-topic on Super User.

Comment: I mod super user. Definitely on topic for a chromebook. You would want to ask on android or apple for their respective platforms but this looks fine